# Order by condition HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, sql-order-by, hql

I have the following tables:

SN, D and C with the following links:

SN contains a FK to D (d_id) (ManyToOne),  SN contains a FK to C (c_id)(OneToOne), C has a FK to D (d_id, OneToOne). D also contains (among other columns a String `number` and a String `name`).

Now, I have a HQL query like this: `"from SN sn where (sn.d is not null or sn.c.d is not null)"` (So, if sn.d is null, take the d from sn.c.d). This set, though, should be sortable by d.number or d.name. Because at query creation time we do not know by which of the "d's" to sort, I have tried like this: 
    `"from SN sn where (sn.d is not null or sn.c.d is not null) order by coalesce (sn.d.name, sn.c.d.name)"` but it is not working, I am getting fewer results than the normal select; I also tried with `"order by case when sn.d is not null then sn.d.name else sn.c.d.name"` but with the same result.

How can I order by the other column if the first one is null in HQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is, with your expression `sn.d.name` you force hibernate to join the tables SN and D internally, with the effect you do not get the rows where sn.d is null, even if sn.c.d is null. Same for `sn.c.d.name`.

Try to define the join between SN and D explicitely as an outer join, something like this:
`from SN sn outer join D d inner join C c where (sn.d is not null or sn.c.d is not null) order by coalesce (d.name, c.d.name)`

For debugging purposes I recommend to set `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` in your hibernate.cfg.xml file. Then you can check what's wrong with the statement hibernate created from your code or to check my proposition (which I didn't test, it might not be 100% correct).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, both left outer join and right outer join give an error: "Path expected for join!". Any ideas?

Comment: Ok solved that problem before sorry for that. Next..I get "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return" because I have a query which expects a list of SNs as result.

Comment: My bad, just had to add: "select sn" at the beginning of the query. It works now!!! so, the query in the end looks like: "select sn from SN sn left outer join sn.d d inner join sn.c c where (sn.d is not null or sn.c.d is not null) order by coalesce (d.name, c.d.name)"